# JAXWS Client ServiceConfigurationError on oracle jdeveloper 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: java, oracle, integration, jax-ws, bi-publisher

I have created a client to connect to oracle fusion webservices. This was done for integration of oracle BI publisher via web services in oracle fusion by using JAXWS.

This integration is currently executing by a batch file from where we are calling the java utility and it is running fine.But as soon as I start executing the java utility from my oracle jdeveloper
(12.2.1.3.0), I get the below error.

I have already added jaxws-tools-2.1.4.jar & jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar jars to my
Classpath & I have tried to find com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.ServiceCreationInterceptor class in jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar but there is no such class exist.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider:   Provider **weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider could not be instantiated**
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:165)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:125)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
        at com.oracle.xmlns.oxp.service.v2.ScheduleService_Service.<init>(ScheduleService_Service.java:46)
        at com.oracle.xmlns.oxp.service.v2.ScheduleServiceClient.runReport(ScheduleServiceClient.java:40)
        at interfaces.YBHRTaleoOLF.JobFullReport(YBHRTaleoOLF.java:49)
        at interfaces.YBHRTaleoOLF.main(YBHRTaleoOLF.java:25)
    **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/ws/api/client/ServiceCreationInterceptor**
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.<clinit>(WLSProvider.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 9 more
    **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.ServiceCreationInterceptor**
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 28 more
    Process exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @user9478789 Were you able to get solution to this?